# Removed some pods, now left with compile error due to derivedData?

Tags: ios, xcode, build, compilation

I removed some pods, and now I'm left with the following error when trying to build. I've tried deleting `derivedData`, clean and clean build-folder, but I'm left with the same result...

```
/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-ggpmikgtclksabvapqmbwhjyudhxw/Build/Intermediates/app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/app.build/Script-A6A86AB51D61DDE700A3B6BF.sh: line 2: /Users/user/Desktop/folder/appfolder/Pods/podsname/run: No such file or directory
```

The pod is Fabric, if that's of any relevance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ran the command for updating the pods you have installed? If not run this command on your project's folder:

```
pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

First Clean the project by command : cmd --> shift --> k
Remove Derived data.
Remove pod folder from your project.
And run the command

```
pod repo remove master
pod setup
pod install
```